# PYTHON: Opening a file with an existing instance using PID

Tags: python

I opened an instance of wordpad.exe. I know the PID.

How can I open, for example, a text file using the same instance?

What I have tried is using subprocess.call(), but that will create a new instance. I would like to use the existing instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't.  Pass the file argument directly to to the program when you are invocing it.

That said, you were able to open a file in a running Wordpad instance in ancient versions of Windows using some OLE magic.  However, this is very specific to Wordpad, and I don't believe it's still supported.